# Tooltip text on a toggle icon - Action or Status

Tags: toggle, tooltips

We have a toggle action icon Lock/Unlock.
In our system, we display the action the button does (e.g. "X" will display the tooltip delete).

the problem is that a toggle button contains both the current status and action to be carried. For example, the tooltip for the lock icon, which signifies the current status is lock, would be "Unlock" as its the action to be carried if clicked.

Do you find this situation plausible?
What alternatives for the tooltip do you suggest (please base it on some article)

Thanks.